# Setting left position in the body of mousemove event listener function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want one of my div's position left value equal to my `mousemove` `event.clientX`. Although individual items in my code works by themselves, following code doesn't work. Why?

```
var shapeCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName("shape")[0];
shapeCanvas.style.left = '1px';  // works 

document.getElementsByClassName("body")[0]
.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
   shapeCanvas.style.left = e.clientX + "px"; // **doesn't work**
   console.log(e.clientX); // works also 
},false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to identify the body element by the body class instead of the tag. I added the eventListener to the window instead, for better results. Is this what you were trying to achieve?

```js
var shapeCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName("shape")[0];
shapeCanvas.style.left = '1px';  // works 

window.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
   shapeCanvas.style.left = e.clientX + "px"; // **doesn't work**
   console.log(e.clientX); // works also 
},false);
```

```css
.shape{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  background:lightblue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="shape">

</div>
```